# DOM manipulation in html variable

Tags: jquery, html, dom, dom-manipulation

I have this string in variable name `data` which have html tags and all

```
<div class="cqr">
  <span class="ico-cqr2 icon-28 star1">quality</span>
  <span class="ico-cqr2 icon-28 star2">quality</span>
  <span class="ico-cqr2 icon-28 star3">quality</span>
  <span class="ico-cqr2 icon-28 star4">quality</span>
  <span class="ico-cqr2 icon-28 star5">quality</span>
</div>
```

I parse this string into html as

```
var tHTML = $.parseHTML(data, null, true);
```

now i need to manipulate the DOM like add/remove some class from span. how can I achieve that.

Comment: Just a note, but in your case, you don't even need to use `.parseHTML()`. `$(data)` will achieve the same result. Note however, this is only true if your string starts with an html tag.

Comment: no it starts with div tag

Comment: You misunderstood, an html tag, as in a valid html tag such as `<div>`, not a literal `<html>` tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(tHTML).find('span').addClass('someClass');
```

As pointed out in the comments, you don't need to use `$.parseHTML`, just put `data` in a jQuery wrapper:

```
$(data).find('span').addClass('someClass');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look around a bit more before asking a question that:

a) Has been asked before

b) Is present on the jquery API: [EDIT: All class functions](http://api.jquery.com/?s=class%28%29)

Example:

```
$('span').removeClass('ico-cqr2, star1');
```

Answer (score 0):

Add class to star1

```
$(tHTML).find('star1').addClass('someClass');
```

Remove class from star1

```
$(tHTML).find('star1').removeClass('someClass');
```

You can manipulate by 'id' ou 'class'
When you put the string between $ () system already handles like a jquery object

How use addClass
http://api.jquery.com/addClass/
How use find
http://api.jquery.com/find/